# Is the class number of the quadratic field $x^2=3\cdot2^n+1$ $O(n)$?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Numerical evidence suggest that the class number of the quadratic field $x^2=3\cdot2^n+1$ is $O(n)$ while the discriminant is $O(2^n)$.

Here are the class numbers for $n=6 \dots 110$ computed with pari/gp:

```
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 48, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 8, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 35, 3, 80, 25, 2, 4, 24, 4, 4, 12, 8, 2, 1, 24, 12, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 4, 13, 104, 4, 2, 1, 8, 4, 8, 400, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 10, 80, 2, 16, 2, 16, 2, 372, 4, 32, 4, 46, 8, 6, 8, 12, 6, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 12, 4, 8, 8, 4, 72
```

[A Monte Carlo factoring algorithm with linear storage](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1984c/art.pdf) possibly might be used to verify for larger $n$, though I don't have working implementation yet.

The motivation is that small class number and the above algorithm might give a divisor of numbers of these form.

I get similar results for $x^2=4\left(3\cdot2^n-1\right)$

For Mersenne numbers $x^2=2^n-1$ there are large class numbers.

```
 1, 1, 4, 2, 8, 2, 4, 1, 16, 4, 48, 9, 16, 1, 16, 2, 256, 2, 272, 4, 520, 4, 1920, 32, 576, 5, 4352, 16, 12168, 16, 6656, 4, 24480, 16, 20416, 4, 8560, 72, 241920, 140352, 498720, 4, 206592, 2, 1494528, 384, 4771328, 32, 758016, 128, 11758848, 8, 19031040, 6, 7610368, 1, 70529424, 16, 246776832, 80, 51142144, 2, 615757824, 16, 1378201600, 8, 900177920, 8, 4452143904, 128, 9139057152, 8, 8201582592, 24, 4530836992, 32, 83129328224, 4, 6856657920, 16, 182429183488, 128, 617893922304, 15, 260395347968, 32, 1944611808768, 4, 3750374341632, 32
```

Comment: The Brauer-Siegel theorem gives some information on the asymptotics of the class number in this situation ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer-Siegel_theorem ). Note that to apply it in your situation, you would have to get some hold on the regulators of your sequence of quadratics fields.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I suspect that the reason that the class numbers seem, vaguely, to be going "big small big small..." alternately in the Mersenne list is that, when $n=2m$ is even, you get a unit $u=2^m+x$ of about as small a height as you could ever hope for, which makes the regulator small so the class group has to be big by Brauer-Siegel.